# How do I extract a desired set of values from a list?

Tags: python, list

I have this code

```
l = ['vbg', 'vkb', 'vv', 'vbj', 'vz',...] #the list continues 

for x in l:
    if len(x) > 2:
        i = l.index (x)
        l.pop(x)
print (l)
```

Output:

```
['vkb','vv','vz']
```

My desired output is this:

```
['vv','vz']
```

I know why this happening but I don't know how to fix this

Comment: Golden rule: Never mutate a list while iterating on it.

Comment: dont modify a list while iterating, create a new one: use `list(filter(lambda x: len(x) < 3,l))` or a list comprehension:  `[e for e in l if len(e) < 3]`

Comment: In this particular case, the iteration "skip" the value `vkb` because its index becomes the index on which the iteration has just occurred after the pop of `vbg`. So, in a hypothetical list of values that all have more than 2 characters, only one element every two will always be deleted

Comment: @PatrickArtner I ran the lambda function but it didn't do anything

Comment: The lamba works properly, did you saved the result somewhere?